# Rewriting query with table join containing GROUP BY clause

Tags: oracle, peoplesoft

Is it possible to rewrite the following query

```
SELECT      CT.GROUP, CT.EMP_ID, HT.EFF_DT
FROM        CURR_TABLE CT
JOIN        (SELECT     GROUP, EMP_ID, MAX(EFF_DT) AS EFF_DT
            FROM        HIST_TABLE
            WHERE       STAT = 'A' 
            GROUP BY    GROUP, EMP_ID) HT ON CT.GROUP = HT.GROUP AND 
            CT.EMPID = HT.EMP_ID
WHERE       CT.GROUP = :1
AND         CT.EMP_ID = :2
```

in a way that is similar to `CROSS JOIN` style?

```
SELECT table1.column1, table2.column2...
FROM  table1, table2 [, table3 ]
```

The reason is that I want to create such query in Peoplesoft, and the above can only be achieved by creating a separate view for the selection with the group by clause. I want to do this just in one query without creating additional views.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try writing your query as a single level join with an aggregation:

```
SELECT
    CT.GROUP,
    CT.EMP_ID,
    MAX(HT.EFF_DT) AS EFF_DT
FROM CURR_TABLE CT
LEFT JOIN HIST_TABLE HT
    ON CT.GROUP = HT.GROUP AND
       CT.EMPID = HT.EMP_ID AND
       HT.STAT = 'A'
WHERE
    CT.GROUP = :1 AND
    CT.EMP_ID = :2
GROUP BY
    CT.GROUP,
    CT.EMP_ID;
```

Note that `GROUP` is a reserved SQL keyword, and you might have to escape it with double quotes to make this query (or the one in your question) work on Oracle.

Comment: Why are you using `LEFT JOIN` instead of `JOIN` ?

Comment: Because it is possible that a given `GROUP/EMP_ID` combination does _not_ have any records where `STAT = 'A'`.  The left join avoids dropping some records from your result set.  If you are not concerned about this, then you may use inner join and move the check on the `STAT` to the `WHERE` clause.